# Why does this command work in Terminal but not in CMD?

Tags: cmd, window, windows-terminal

```
Dopusrt.exe /acmd Go "c:/"
```

The above command works, last active Window goes to `c:/` but the below command does not work.

```
Dopusrt.exe /info documents\filelist1.txt,listsel,0
```

The weird thing is it works just fine in Windows Terminal. Does CMD reserve commas for something? I really need to use CMD in this case, Since Auotohotkey seems to only speak to CMD.

Thank you.

Comment: Just a friendly, neighborhood reminder that questions on Stack Overflow should be regarding *"specific coding, algorithm, or language problems."* Your question would likely be better suited for [Super User](https://superuser.com), but please be sure to familiarize yourself with that site's rules for posting as well.

Answer (score 1):

CMD and Windows Terminal are not the same type of application. CMD is a *shell*, and WT is a *terminal*. See [this post](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/blob/main/doc/Niksa.md#shell-vs-terminal) for more details.

You can run any shell you'd like in WT - CMD, PowerShell, whatever.

CMD.exe does not by itself reserve commas (to the best of my knowledge). And running cmd.exe in WT vs running it in conhost (the default console on Windows) shouldn't make a difference either.